# Is this a harmonic riff?

Tags: scales, harmony, key, songwriting

Here's the riff.
[image]

For me a harmonic riff sounds harmonic. Without any thinking about the theory I can hear it most of the times. But in this case I'm not sure. Especially `G 1` sounds a little bit off.

Does a riff needs to remain in the same scale (for example in a specific pentatponic)? Or can I change the scale within one repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit for the updated question: No, a riff does not have to stay within the same scale; you can change the scale (or not use a scale at all) to create a riff.**

---

### Original Answer Below

Maybe a more correct question (i.e., not opinion-based) would have been "what is a riff," and that could have then progressed to whether your excerpt is correct.

Mark Spicer has a great article called [“(Ac)cumulative Form in Pop-Rock Music”](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/twentieth-century-music/article/accumulative-form-in-poprock-music/37CF5D672DD0096EB81A30CE911372BC), and he defines a riff as "a distinctive melodic/rhythmic idea in the manner of an ostinato." (An "ostinato" is just a repeated figure.)

Thus it seems you have a three-bar idea that's then repeated, with a slight variation in the melody in measures 4--6. (So it might be a six-bar riff, depending on how you repeat it.)

We can't answer whether it's "good" or not---that's ultimately your call!---but I would suggest reading up a bit on keys and note spellings; I think you'd be better off spelling all of your sharps as flats (D♯ becomes E♭, etc.), because it looks like you're aiming for C minor.